# How to add JavaScript variable value to CSS variable?

Tags: javascript, css, variables

Trying to use Window.innerWidth and load the received value into a CSS variable, but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  
  document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--window', w);}
```

```css
:root {
  --window:0px;
}

div {
  
  height: calc(var(--window) / 2);
  background:red;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think you have to write a new stylesheet.

Comment: If an answer was helpful to you, you should accept it with the checkmark on the left of it.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons:

1. You are not calling `myFunction`, only defining it.
2. `window.innerWidth` returns a number without units (which represent pixels). In order for it to be a valid `height` value, you should add `px` as a suffix.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--window', `${w}px`);
}
myFunction();
```

```css
:root {
  --window: 0px;
}

div {
  height: calc(var(--window) / 2);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Another thing you might not know: `var()` accepts a default value. If `--window` is only used once, you can write the property as `height: calc(var(--window, 0px) / 2);` and omit the `:root` ruleset.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the rule dynamically, to the style-sheet using a `insertRule` or `addRule`.

Please review [*"Add Rules to Stylesheets with JavaScript"*](https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) by David Walsh.

```js
// See: https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets
const addCSSRules = (sheet, selector, rules, index = 1) => {
  if (typeof rules !== 'string') {
    rules = Object.entries(rules).map(entry => entry.join(':')).join(';');
  }
  if ('insertRule' in sheet) {
    sheet.insertRule(`${selector} {${rules}}`, index);
  } else if ('addRule' in sheet) {
    sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
  }
}

const [ sheet ] = document.styleSheets;

addCSSRules(sheet, ':root', {
  '--window': `${window.innerWidth}px`
});
```

```css
:root {
  --window: 0px;
}

div {
  height: calc(var(--window) / 2);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```